# Relay.Renderer render callback doesn't expose fetched data

Tags: relayjs

I have a problem with `render` callback in `Relay.Renderer`.

```js
export const renderCallback = ({ done, error, retry, stale, props, element }) => {

    console.log(props)

    // if returning undefined, previously rendered view is rendered
    return undefined
}
```

`props` is `null` until it fetches the data and when it's finally not `null`, it **doesn't** contain fetched data.

For example, if it's node query, logged `props.node` is the following:

```js
node: {
    __dataID__: "AH4zdDo1ODBjYVWkZTZmNzFgDSJmMTg1YQQ5Y2E="
    __fragments__: {
        4::client: [
            0: {
                postId: null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Component actually has the data but it doesn't expose it in `Relay.Renderer` `render` callback.

---

**Is this normal and how to access the Relay fetched data in `render` callback?**

Comment: Hello, it's not normal. We are missing the code that actually creates the container, could you post it ?

Comment: You mean `Relay.createContainer`? Im not using `Relay.RootContainer` @whitep4nther

Comment: I mean `Renderer` yes, but also `createContainer`. In fact, your code ;)

Comment: @Solo Did you ever solve this problem? I too am getting props such as those posted above.

Comment: No but it seems that it's built this way, because data is available in component. @ChrisHarrison

Comment: @Solo Yep, but it's a shame. Because I want to be able to stop rendering in the component, if certain props are certain values. I don't want to do that logic in the render method of the component because that will force a refresh which animates a flash of content.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the parameter of Relay.Renderer render

Like this https://github.com/sibelius/ExNavRelay/blob/master/src/RelayUtils.js#L114

Comment: Im actually using it, if you look at my question, like this: `render={renderCallback}`

Comment: render function is called more than one time, u need to render a loading indicator until Relay get the props from the server

Comment: Yes, Im aware of that. My problem is that if data is finally fetched by Relay, it's not available in `render` function in `props`.

Comment: could u try to use createRendere of RelayUtils like this: https://github.com/sibelius/ExNavRelay/blob/master/src/UserList.js#L119, and see if the error still happens?